# Is the language $\{ w \in \{ a, b \}^{*} | |w|_{a} + |w|_{b} = 2^{n} \}$ context sensitive?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, context-sensitive

Is the language $\{  w \in \{ a, b \}^{*} : |w|_{a} + |w|_{b} = 2^{n} \}$ context sensitive ?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: $|w|_a+|w|_b=<something>$ - for $w\in\{a,b\}∗$, how is this different from $|w|=<something>$?

Answer (score 2):

A language is context-sensitive if and only if it can be recognised by a linearly bounded automaton (LBA). To show that $L$ is context-sensitive it is therefore enough to construct an LBA that recognises it. The idea behind the LBA is to repeatedly scan the input from left to right and mark symbols. In every such pass, mark every other unmarked symbol, starting with the first unmarked aymbol. Use a parity check (which can be recorded in the state of the machine) to check that this is done correctly - alternating between parity $0$ and $1$. If at some point the marking process cannot continue when the machine has parity state $1$, then reject. Else, if the machine is in parity state $0$, accept. The underlying idea behind this is to repeatedly divide the length of the string by $2$ to see if we eventually reach $0$.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Answer (score -2):

If I understand the notation correctly (summing the amount of a's and amount of b's) and checking if it if a power of 2, then I do not believe it is context sensitive.

Comment: If a homomorphism is taken from  { w \in { a, b }^{*} | |w|_{a} + |w|{b} = 2^{n} , n \geq 0 } to {a}^{*} by h(a) = a, h(b) = a, then it becomes {a^{2^{n}} | n \geq 0 \}. It is context-sensitive. Context sensitive languages are closed under non-erasing morphism . So, it makes  { w \in { a, b }^{*} | |w|{a} + |w|{b} = 2^{n}, n \geq 0 } context sensitive.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).